# Pubnub hereNow: Issues with variable scope & threads

Tags: multithreading, scope, pubnub

Here is my code.

I am trying to check if a subscriber with a specific ID is subscribed to my channel.

```
public class HubActions {
    private boolean reply;

    public boolean isConnected(String id, String chan) {

        String subKey = "sub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String pubKey = "pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub(pubKey, subKey);


        Callback callback = new Callback() {
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                    JSONArray uuids = new JSONArray();
                    uuids = json.getJSONArray("uuids");

                    for(int i=0;i<json.getInt("occupancy");i++) {
                        if(uuids.get(i).equals(id)) {
                            System.out.println("Yup!");
                            reply = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                System.out.println(error.toString());
            }
        };
        pubnub.hereNow(chan, callback);

        return reply;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean b = new HubActions().isConnected("2", "2_sub");
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Here is my output

> false 
>   {"occupancy":2,"service":"Presence","message":"OK","status":200,"uuids":["2","3bbe065c-d84a-4529-a641-26d05439e71d"]} 
>   Yup!

I dont understand why **false** is returned even though the function clearly assigns **true** to value of boolean variable *reply*

I understand that when we create an instance of pubnub 2 threads are initialized. I think it might be that the threads are still processing while the function returns the default value of variable *reply*

But how do I resolve this?

Comment: What negative side affect is the false causing? This isn't something that should be a concern though.

Comment: @CraigConover: The program is supposed to check if a UUID is subscribed to a channel. It should return true if it is subscribed & false if its not subscribed. But as you can see from my output, even though we can see that the UUID array contains the value I need, it still returns false.

Answer (score 0):

This is an async issue. You are calling `hereNow`, and it is returning immediately and then you are outputting the value of `reply` while the successCallback is getting called asynchronously and running the loop.

That is why you see the value of `reply` get displayed before the *Yup* is displayed. Do this instead:

```
public class HubActions {
    private boolean reply;

    public boolean isConnected(String id, String chan) {

        String subKey = "sub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String pubKey = "pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub(pubKey, subKey);


        Callback callback = new Callback() {
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                    JSONArray uuids = new JSONArray();
                    uuids = json.getJSONArray("uuids");

                    for(int i=0;i<json.getInt("occupancy");i++) {
                        if(uuids.get(i).equals(id)) {
                            System.out.println("Yup!");
                            reply = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // output value of reply here
                    // or implement your own listener for the 
                    // caller to receive the update
                    System.out.println(reply);

                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                System.out.println(error.toString());
            }
        };
        pubnub.hereNow(chan, callback);

        return reply;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean b = new HubActions().isConnected("2", "2_sub");
        // b will always be false due to async nature of code
        // must implement a listener to get the result from this scope
        // System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am punting on the real solution, which is to implement a listener pattern the `successCallback` code and call to notify the orginal caller in `main`.

All I did was comment out your `System.out.println(b)` as that will always be `false` and doing `System.out.println(reply)` in the `successCallback` after the for loop has terminated.